# Minimum number of speakers needed for 3D Audio

Tags: audio, speakers, experiences, 3d

I am planning to create a *3D Audio experience* in a small room. For that I would like to place speakers around the center of the room. How many speakers do I need minimum to play sounds, for example from the left, the top, the front and back, etc?

I thought about using 3 speakers on the floor in a triangle-formation as well as one at the ceiling. Would that work? Placing 8 speakers (one in every corner) seems a bit to much.

Comment: This kind of sounds like you're trying to reinvent the wheel. You *can* sort of do this with 8 speakers [5.1.2], 6 if you're going to sacrifice the centre & sub, but it feels like what you want is a Dolby Atmos structure, which really wants 9 or more [7.1.4]. If you're going to be driving this from a dedicated multi-channel playback structure, you're going to need something that can actually handle this as discrete channels right through. Atmos can be driven through consumer-level receivers [decoders/amps] from a 'stereo' output.

Comment: Here's a simple consumer guide to Atmos - https://www.the-home-cinema-guide.com/dolby-atmos-complete-guide.html

Comment: I believe there was a commercial system similar to the tetrahedral model you're describing (3 on the ground and one above) as far back as the 70s but @Tetsujin is right. It would be cheaper and easier to buy an existing 3D sound system than to do all the processing yourself.

Comment: Wave Field Synthesis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_field_synthesis is an interesting approach to create a 3D soundscape in a room but it requires many loudspeakers.